# Расположение элементов в Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, gui, graphics

Мне надо сделать пару кнопок на панели в Java Swing и, конечно, хотелось бы, чтобы они были одного размера. Пока я тупо наставил пробелов, но получилась ерунда какая-то. Плюс ко всему, я хотел бы пропустить немного места на панели и добавить туда еще кнопок, но как это сделать не понимаю.

**Скрин с программой:**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Код программы, описывающий панель справа:**

```
JPanel eastPanel = new JPanel();
eastPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(eastPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

startButton = new JButton("Старт       ");
startButton.addActionListener(new StartButtonListener());
startButton.setSize(20, 40);
stopButton = new JButton("Стоп         ");
stopButton.addActionListener(new StopButtonListener());
stopButton.setSize(20, 40);
JButton clearButton = new JButton("Очистить");
clearButton.addActionListener(new ClearButtonListener());
clearButton.setSize(20, 40);

startButton.setSize(clearButton.getSize());
stopButton.setSize(clearButton.getSize());


eastPanel.add(startButton);
eastPanel.add(stopButton);
eastPanel.add(clearButton);
```

[**Весь проект целиком**](https://github.com/Faoxis/KatinDipsach)

Comment: Используйте [менеджер слоёв](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/layoutlist.html). С помощью GridBagLayout, например, можно сделать кнопки в 2 столбца.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Откройте для себя такие слои как GridBagLayout и GridLayout. Они помогут решить многие проблемы.

```
        GridBagConstraints layConstraints;

    JPanel eastPanel = new JPanel();
    eastPanel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(4, 4, 4, 4)); // отступ внутри панели на 4 пикселя со всех сторон
        GridBagLayout layout = new GridBagLayout();
        layout.rowHeights = new int[]{23, 23, 23, 0}; // высоты кнопок
        layout.columnWeights = new double[]{1.0};
        layout.rowWeights = new double[]{0.0, 0.0, 0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
        eastPanel.setLayout(layout);

    startButton = new JButton("Старт");
    startButton.addActionListener(new StartButtonListener());

        layConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        layConstraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH; // заполняет ячейку целиком
        layConstraints.gridx = 0; // координаты ячейки, в которую помещается кнопка
        layConstraints.gridy = 0;
        eastPanel.add(startButton, layConstraints); // добавление кнопки на панель с учётом разметки

    stopButton = new JButton("Стоп");
    stopButton.addActionListener(new StopButtonListener());

        layConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        layConstraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        layConstraints.gridx = 0;
        layConstraints.gridy = 1;
        eastPanel.add(stopButton, layConstraints);

    JButton clearButton = new JButton("Очистить");
    clearButton.addActionListener(new ClearButtonListener());

        layConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        layConstraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        layConstraints.gridx = 0;
        layConstraints.gridy = 2;
        eastPanel.add(clearButton, layConstraints);
```