# Swing javа кнопки

Tags: java, swing

Почему в окне выводится только кнопка button3, притом, на весь экран?
Код:

```
public class InterfaceCalq extends JFrame{
private JButton button0 = new JButton("Формулы куба");
private JButton button1 = new JButton("Формулы сферы");
private JButton button2 = new JButton("Формулы круга");
private JButton button3 = new JButton("Формулы цилиндра");

public InterfaceCalq(){
    super("Калькулятор по формулам");
    this.setBounds(200,200,300,450);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    Container container = this.getContentPane();
    container.add(button0);
    container.add(button1);
    container.add(button2);
    container.add(button3);
}
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        InterfaceCalq app = new InterfaceCalq();
        app.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

вопрос в том, как сделать так,чтобы кнопки отображались в столбик и как задать им размер?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дело в том, что button3 перекрывает все кнопки, которые идут до неё, т.к. ваше окно, это одно сплошное поле. Вам нужно воспользоваться менеджером компоновки и в нём уже размещать кнопки.

Подробнее:

[На английском](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)
[На русском](http://www.quizful.net/post/swing-layout-managers)

Answer (score 2):

Я уже задавал подобный вопрос и получил очень хороший ответ. [Посмотрите](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/522674/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-java-swing).
GridBagLayout - действительно очень хороший инструмент для расположения элементов. Чем раньше вы начнете им пользоваться, тем большего количества проблем сможете избежать.